# Traffic shaping on shared internet connection

Tags: macos, networking, osx-lion, ipfw

I'm running OS X Lion, and I'm trying to simulate low bandwidth connection (like 3G, EDGE, etc.) over a shared internet connection to android devices.

The application that runs on the android devices talks directly using the local IP with each other.

I tried setting some IPFW rules, but it only limit the connectivity to the Internet and not between the two devices.

How can I limit the direct connection between the two devices when they are both connected to the shared internet connection on my MacBook?

Thanks.

Comment: See [this SuperUser question](http://superuser.com/questions/403297/how-do-i-simulate-a-slow-internet-connection-on-os-x)

Comment: I've seen it. The problem is, that it doesn't affect the traffic between two devices that both connect to the MacBook hotspot. It's only affects the traffic between a device and the internet.